# Minimum number of bytes that can contain an integer value

Tags: c#, integer, bit-manipulation

Given an integer value, I need some way to find out the minimum number of bytes needed to store the value. The value may be *signed or unsigned, up to 64-bit*. Also take the sign bit into account for signed integers.

For example:

```
                          8     requires 1 byte at minimum
               unsigned 255     requires 1 byte at minimum
                 signed 255     requires 2 bytes at minimum
                       4351     requires 2 bytes at minimum
                -4294967296     requires 5 bytes at minimum
unsigned 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF     requires 8 bytes at minimum
```

I can think of a quick-and-dirty way to solve this, using many if-statements, but there might be better (e.g. simpler, cleverer, faster) ways to do this. You may either assume a method with signature `int (long value, bool signed)` or two methods `int (long value)` (for signed) and `int (ulong value)` (for unsigned).

Comment: You need two inputs (long val, bool signed), right?

Comment: Correct, `(long value, bool signed)` would satisfy the requirements of it being signed or unsigned, up to 64-bit. But it might also be two methods, one `(long value)` the other `(ulong value)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me give it a go at my own question. As far as I can tell, this is a correct solution, but it may not be optimal in speed, conciseness:

```
public static int GetMinByteSize(long value, bool signed)
{
    ulong v = (ulong)value;
    // Invert the value when it is negative.
    if (signed && value < 0)
        v = ~v;
    // The minimum length is 1.
    int length = 1;
    // Is there any bit set in the upper half?
    // Move them to the lower half and try again.
    if ((v & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) != 0)
    {
        length += 4;
        v >>= 32;
    }
    if ((v & 0xFFFF0000) != 0)
    {
        length += 2;
        v >>= 16;
    }
    if ((v & 0xFF00) != 0)
    {
        length += 1;
        v >>= 8;
    }
    // We have at most 8 bits left.
    // Is the most significant bit set (or cleared for a negative number),
    // then we need an extra byte for the sign bit.
    if (signed && (v & 0x80) != 0)
        length++;
    return length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static int BytesForNum(long value, bool signed)
{
    if (value == 0)
        return 1;
    if (signed)
    {
        if (value < 0)
            return CalcBytes(2 * (-1-value));
        else
            return CalcBytes(2 * value);
    }
    else
    {
        if (value < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Can't represent a negative unsigned number", "value");
        return CalcBytes(value);
    }
}
//should only be called with positive numbers
private static int CalcBytes(long value)
{
    int bitLength = 0;
    while (value > 0)
    {
        bitLength++;
        value >>= 1;
    }
    return (int)(Math.Ceiling(bitLength * 1.0 / 8));
}
```

I might not have the signed code exactly right, but that's the general idea.

Comment: So if I pass the values ((long)[UInt64.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint64.maxvalue.aspx), false) then I get an exception?

Comment: If you try to do that outside of an `unchecked` context, you'll get a compile error.  But that brings up a good point: my code will fail if `value` is larger than about `long.MaxValue / 2` and `signed` is `true`.  A simple if can fix this.

Comment: Is that `CalcBytes` function actually save? Is `Math.Log` guaranteed to be accurate enough?

Comment: Good point.  I've replaced it with code using bit shifts.  That should be perfectly accurate.

Comment: You code cannot handle all cases in my post (more precisely any number greater than `Int64.MaxValue` when signed is `false`) and is incorrect for at least `0x8000000000000000`, `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` (-1) and signed `0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` as it returns a value of 0, which is obviously wrong. And isn't `-1-x` the same as `~x`?

Comment: If you want to handle values larger than `long.MaxValue`, you have to take a `ulong` (or `BigInteger`), in which case you don't need a `signed` flag.  As for the other bugs and comments: I figured my code wouldn't handle every case, and you seem to be on a good track of figuring out all the problem cases.  The only ones that have problems should be very large values, e.g. within a bit of your number type's `MaxValue`.  You can throw `if`s in to handle these cases.  If you dislike how it's turning out, you can always revert to a chain of `if`s like `if (value <= 255) return 1`.

Comment: ''Unsigned'' values larger than `long.MaxValue` are very valid and real values that the code should be able to handle. I found the values that it does not handle just by trying them. I don't dislike your solution, but when it is incomplete and sometimes wrong/bugged, or requires multiple changes to make it work, then you'll just lower the chance of getting the accept-tick.