# Convert int to different size of byte array

Tags: c#, byte, arrays

I have a byte array `result`. I would like to convert my type called `Info` which are all `int` to the byte array but all of them are in different size.

> a = 4 bytes
>
> b = 3 bytes
>
> c = 2 bytes
>
> d = 1 bytes

This is the code I've tried.

```
private byte[] getInfoByteArray(Info data)
{
    byte[] result = new byte[10];
    BitConverter.GetBytes((data.a)).CopyTo(result, 0);
    BitConverter.GetBytes((data.b)).CopyTo(result, 4);
    BitConverter.GetBytes((data.c)).CopyTo(result, 7);
    result [9] = Convert.ToByte(data.d);

    return result;
    }
```

However, I found out that `BitConverter.GetBytes` returns 4 bytes.

Are there any general solutions that can get different size of bytes to a byte array?

Comment: `int` is always stored as 4 bytes. `GetBytes()` doesn't always only return byte arrays that are 4 long, it's only doing that because you're using the `int` data type. You could use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11651620/74757) to calculate the minimum number of bytes needed to hold your integer values (presumable returning the 4, 3, 2, and 1 sizes as listed), then trim the result of `.GetBytes()` to that length before copying to your final byte array.

Comment: It's not clear why you want different byte lengths for your fields, especially if they are all actually `int` types. If you are sure you really only need 3, 2, or 1 byte for b, c, and d, then c and d can be `short` and `byte`, giving you exactly what you need. Your result for b depends on endianness, but you can truncate the array, e.g. `Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(data.b), 0, result, 4, 3)`. I.e. if you don't want all the bytes, then **don't copy all the bytes**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.Copy(Array, Int32, Array, Int32, Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
byte[] result = new byte[10];
Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(data.a), 0, result, 0, 4);
Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(data.b), 0, result, 4, 3);
Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(data.c), 0, result, 7, 2);
Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(data.d), 0, result, 9, 1);
```

This assumes little endian hardware. If your hardware is big endian, use

```
byte[] result = new byte[10];
Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(data.a), 0, result, 0, 4);
Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(data.b), 1, result, 4, 3);
Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(data.c), 2, result, 7, 2);
Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(data.d), 3, result, 9, 1);
```